# Undefined value from looping through json

Tags: javascript, typescript

In typescript/javascript I'm trying to fetch 'statute' from data object:

{_id: "31ad2", x: 21.29, y: -157.81, law: "290-11",....}

So I assign data.law to a variable. But, I'm getting typeerror cannot read property 'law' of undefined?

If I console log 'data.law' at line 11 or result[0] at the line 18 I get the correct value...

```
sectionsSuccess(res: Response) {
  this.allSections = [];
    this.sections = [];
    this.loadingSections = false;
    try {
      let jsonRes = res.json();
      this.jsonResLength = jsonRes.length;
      for (var a = 0; a < this.jsonResLength; a++) {
        let js = jsonRes[a];
        js.bookmarked = this.server.isInBookmark(js);
        this.allSections.push(js);
        if (a < 15) {
          this.sections[a] = this.allSections[a];
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      alert("Exception: " + e.message);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < this.allSections.length; i++) {
      this.allSections[i] = this.convertLocationDataToStatutes(this.allSections[i]);
    }
// complete code added above
  for (var i = 0; i < this.sections.length; i++) {
    this.sections[i] = this.convertLocationDataToStatutes(this.sections[i]);
  }
}
  convertLocationDataToStatutes(data: any): any {
    var self = this;
    var chapterandsection = data.law; //line 11
    var values = chapterandsection.split('-');
    var chapter = values[0];
    var section = values[1];
    (self.server).getSection(chapter, section)
      .map(response => response.json()).subscribe(result => {
      return result[0];  // line 18
    });
  }
```

Comment: Where do you define data and what is the value of data? Where do you call it?

Comment: what is `this.sections` defined as ? check if you are passing any undefined value in `this.sections[i] = this.convertLocationDataToStatutes(this.sections[i]);`

Comment: Added complete function for sectionsSuccess

Comment: Did you have any questions about my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Your `convertLocationDataToStatutes` never returns anything, but you're using its return value. The result of calling a function with no return value is `undefined`. So the loop fills `this.sections` with a bunch of `undefined`s. That means the *next* time `sectionsSuccess` gets called, it will see `undefined` in `this.sections[x]`, and accessing `data.law` on it will cause the error. So the problem will present the *second* time `sectionsSuccess` is called; your logging of `data.law` where you saw the value presumably was the **first** call to it.

The only `return` in `convertLocationDataToStatutes` is the one inside the `subscribe` callback. Presumably you meant to return something from `convertLocationDataToStatutes` itself.

Comment: yes because this.sections[i] is getting reassigned each time the loop runs

Comment: @PeterRader: The claim that logging `data.law` on line 11 is most likely observational error, seeing ones from the *first* pass through the loop, not realizing the error is from a *subsequent* pass through the loop (in a subsequent call to `sectionsSuccess`). I did say, quite clearly, that the problem would present on the *next* call after the one filling `sections` with `undefine`. (The `console.log` on line 18 is *also* in the `subscribe` callback, so isn't the return value of the function.) I've now emphasized that in the answer.